# Remove docking combo button from AvalonDock LayoutAnchorable

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, avalondock

I'm developing a vb.net WPF application (not using MVVM) that contains an AvalonDock LayoutAnchorable. What I want to know is, is there a way to remove the built-in Down-Arrow combo button that provides docking options from the LayoutAnchorable?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that there is an option to hide the drop-down button completely out-of-the-box. The anchorables do not seem to provide any properties or methods for hiding the button or customizing the header template easily.

However, you can remove the button for all anchorables by modifying the `AnchorablePaneTitle` style. You can find the default styles depening on your theme [on GitHub](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/tree/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src) in one of the `Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.*` directories. The styles are defined in `Theme.xaml`. You most likely use *Aero*, if you did not specify anything else.

Copy the style, e.g. [*Aero*](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/9b694aa76c399bea71b08da470d3deadfb0c2d79/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.Aero/Theme.xaml#L450), to a resource dictionary in scope or the application resources. Then you can go to the drop-down button definition and set its `Visibility` to `Collapsed`. Do not delete this part, it is easier to simply hide it.

```
<xcad:DropDownButton x:Name="MenuDropDownButton"
                     Visibility="Collapsed"
                     ... />
```

Keep in mind that this is not an easy edit, as it requires you to adapt the XML namespaces to the ones that you have imported in your XAML file and adapting the file paths to point to the right assembly, e.g.:

- `avalonDockProperties:Resources.Anchorable_BtnAutoHide_Hint` would become `xcad:Resources.Anchorable_BtnAutoHide_Hint` for me, as I have added the corresponding namespce as `xmlns:xcad="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"`
- The file path `Images/PinAutoHide_Dark.png` is only valid in the source assembly, so it would become `pack://application:,,,/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.Aero;component/Images/PinClose_Dark.png`
  ``

You could also reset the `AnchorableContextMenu`. It would prevent the context menu on the anchorables from showing up. If you did not modify the template, it would also prevent the drop-down button from showing any menu items, but the drop-down button would still be visible and clickable.

```
<xcad:DockingManager AnchorableContextMenu="{x:Null}">
```

Look at this image for a comparsion of the original and the modified template.

[image: Anchorables comparison]